# Find all the possible combinations by SPARQL based on values

Tags: sparql, rdf, knapsack-problem

I'm wondering if the SPARQL can solve the following problem. And how the SPARQL query should be written for such a problem (similar to knapsack problem).

I have 50 dollars in the pocket that I want to buy some books, here is the price list of books in triples:

```
:book1 :hasPrice :15 .
:book2 :hasPrice :20 .
:book3 :hasPrice :25 .
```

I want to know all the possible combinations of books that I can buy. It's obvious that the possible combinations here are:

```
book1
book2
book3
book1 book2
book2 book3
book1 book3
```

But how I can query for these combinations by using SPARQL? Thank you in advance!

Comment: no way in SPARQL. I mean, you'd need some kind of loop which adds one more book in each iteration and checks if it's still a valid combination. I also don't see why one would use SPARQL here. It's a query language for RDF, something like the knapsack problem is solved via some dynamic programming algorithm or even just approximated with some greedy stuff. All SPARQL can do is to give you the cartesian product, but not something like the powerset. Of course I might be wrong and people much smarter than me will give you a solution

Comment: @AKSW Thank you! But is it possible to achieve by Rules (like SWRL)?